# How to Show input type(hidden) in a form

Tags: html, forms, text, input, hidden

In a form with 3 buttons(view,copy and edit) and other kinds of information already visibled I want to show an input text when I press the edit button. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <button onClick="document.getElementById('field1').type = 'text'">Edit</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="field1">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Vdrr/)

Comment: Perfect! And if instead of a text box was another button?Should I change text with button right?

Comment: Yes, changing 'text' with 'button' seems to work.